# React Google Map component not switching between 2D and 3D view after page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

React - Google Map component not able to switch from 2D to 3D after page refresh

I'm am trying to integrate google maps on 2d and 3d where the user can switch on either options. I have created a Parent Function with two onclick handlers one for 2D view and the other for 3D view. The onclick sets the state value to either true or false and the value is sent to the child function where google map is implemented. When I click on the onclick handlers the map switches from 2D to 3D as expected, but as soon as the page is refreshed, even though I can see the values passed across from the parent to the child to be correct, the map fails to switch until I comment out the streetViewPanorama and refresh the page and add it back again, before it works as expected. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the parent page

```
function PropertyDetail(props) {

  const [state, setstate] = useState(false);

  const isEnabled = state;

return (     <article>
                <Box>
                  <h2>
                    Points of interest
                  </h2>
                  <Box>
                    <ul>
                      <li onClick={() => setstate(false)}>
                        Map
                      </li>
                      <li onClick={() => setstate(true)}>
                        3D
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </Box>
                  <Box>
                    <Box>
                      <PointOfInterest isEnabled={isEnabled} />
                    </Box>
                  </Box>
                </Box>
              </article>)
```

The child page

```
import { useMemo } from "react";
import {
  GoogleMap,
  MarkerF,
  StreetViewPanorama,
  useLoadScript,
} from "@react-google-maps/api";
import "./pointofinterest.css";

const PointOfInterst = (props) => {
  const { isLoaded } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  });

  const center = useMemo(() => ({ lat: 7.4192661, lng: 3.8761708 }), []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {!isLoaded ? (
        <h1>Loading...</h1>
      ) : (
        <GoogleMap
          mapContainerClassName="map-container"
          center={center}
          zoom={17}
        >
          <StreetViewPanorama
            options={{ position: center, visible: props.isEnabled }}
          />
          <MarkerF position={{ lat: 7.4192661, lng: 3.8761708 }} />
        </GoogleMap>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PointOfInterst;
```

Even when the props.isEnabled is true the map doesn't switch to the StreetViewPanorama after a page refresh.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you provide a code sandbox of your code that we can play around with?

Comment: I just added it to code sandbox and it seems to be fine, but on my dev environment I had to implement a work around to have it working as expected. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wild-fast-5r3hxl?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A48%2C31

Comment: I checked the codesandbox, and it looks like the streetViewPanorama is not unmounted in your mentioned page refresh, or if I press the default back button. It is only unmounted when I click the custom Map buttonn to switch views.

Comment: Maybe you can try utilizing `onVisibleChanged` props to trigger the setState of your map and streetview.